# How to design a relational database that stores snapshots of tables?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have the following tables:

- products
- companies
- purchases (has one company, has many products)

I need to be able to create invoices based on the above 3 tables.
The problem I'm facing is that **since the products are editable one could change the price, thus making the invoice invalid: the price of the product is no longer the same price when the purchase happened**

I thought about storing the total price on the purchase table (this would allow me to get a total price of the purchase), but I need to display more granular data on the invoice, on a per product basis.

The same problem happens with linking companies to purchases. If I need to store the invoices on a table, the invoice will always reflect the most current data, which is not ideal. Editing products would change every stored invoice that relates to a particular product that was edited.

Yet a third problem arises when it comes to making reports based on multiple measures that are all stored in different tables. I can never make an accurate report for a point in time if I keep updating related tables.

Really what I need is "time travel" I think. I've considered a few options:

- Create a "snapshot" table for each table, with the same schema etc. These snapshot tables would be then linked to the tables I need to use for reporting, invoicing and such.
- The above but using the same tables. Any row with a parent_id would be a snapshot.
- When editing products, create new products instead, and keep the original untouched.

This last one seems the worst solution. What is this problem called that I'm facing in general terms? How can I go about it?

**by "linking" I mean setting up relationships using foreign keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to solve this is very simple, I deal with prices , products and invoices everyday.

Create a product_price table, where you store product id, current price, and dates that let you check the time period when each price was valid. So you will have a one product to many prices, each of one reflecting validity dates.  That way on the table that stores invoices instead of inserting the product id, insert product_id_price.

The same goes to any attribute of the product itself, register changes on the basis of validity.

When reporting, you will be able to relate product and valid price at the moment of purchase based on the product_id_price, or whatever attribute.

The need of dates in the product price table obeys to the need to repor historical evolution of prices or any attribute.

If your products dramatically change over time, consider the business logic before modelling data.  Data must reflect the business logic.  Having said that, I recommend, and I use it, create an overarching family table that parents each product, for example FORD FOCUS parents the different sku's that holds the name Ford Focus, but differ in some attributes.

Comment: I understand that would work well, but in my case I need to be able to do the same for any column on the product table. I'd have a table for each column, like product_taxes (or for the company example, company_ibans, company_address, company_{any attribute I use in the invoice} Is that an OK way to go about it considering I'll end up with 30+ tables?

Comment: There are basically three choices. (1) Stamp out the values in the invoice. (2) Go the historical id route and perform joins later, (3) Don't have the values or ids in the invoice but fetch them later with tricky "what was the effective value at that time" based on other tables with rows for effective datetime and that value. Thoughts: 3 can be a complete disaster.

Comment: @Tamás if your product changes in so many attributes, maybe your products are different, so its better to create an overarching family of products, and adding family members, instead of modifying a product many times so becomes really different from previous.

Comment: While I don't think there's any harm in storing all this information in the way datelligence has suggested, I would also have an invoice detail table which unambiguously stores the facts as they were at the time of the invoice.

Comment: I usually store at invoice table, date of transaction, customer, pos machine, store, and total amount, and also have and invoice detail table where I store the minimun granularity, that is product_id_price

Comment: @Tamás the community has helped you with great and useful knowledge in the form of comments and answer, so please standing in line with stackoverflow's sharing and community generosity, be kind and accept any answer.  We are sure that our comments and answers were helpful to you. thanks.

Comment: He has an ok track record of accepts. Sometimes takes a while. Here's my support.

Comment: I appreciate your help, however it's not fair to ask me to accept an answer because I have no way to tell right now whether a proposed solution works better than another one. In any case, I've accepted your answer, hope the other community members won't get offended.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new column in the purchasing table called PurchaseSnapshot and insert all necessary values that have the potential of changing in the future. Not sure what your UI is like, but you could change the code to go off the snapshot values (price) rather easily, or you could load the snapshot info into a simple textbox and use as reference

Comment: That seems the most simple idea. I could store the data in json format. It leaves me little flexibility for reporting though since I'm gonna have to do some computations at the application level. I guess I'm gonna have to try and see if it scales... Quite a gamble really.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is version some of your data. The details of versioning is much too long to try to provide in a simple answer. [Here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/114580/best-way-to-design-a-database-and-table-to-keep-records-of-changes/114738#114738) is an answer I gave to a similar question which contains a link to a slide presentation I made which contains details of how to design the tables and write the queries to retrieve the data.

The listed advantages of this method is that the past and current data (and future data, if used) reside in the same tables so the same query is used to look at the data at some time in the past or the data as it is in the present. Also, referential integrity works the same with versioned data as non-versioned. The lack of foreign keys to versioned data has always been a real show-stopper for versioning.

See if this will work for you.